# z complex $p, q \in \mathbb{N}, p < q$ such that $|z ^ p + \frac {1}{z ^ p}| \ge |z ^ q + \frac {1}{z ^ q}|$, so $|z + \frac{1}{z}| < 2$

Tags: complex-numbers, modules, contest-math

I have participated yesterday in a contest. One of the problems was this one:
If $x \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ and there exists $p, q \in \mathbb{N}, p < q$ such that $|z ^ p + \frac {1}{z ^ p}| \ge |z ^ q + \frac {1}{z ^ q}|$, we need to prove $|z + \frac{1}{z}| \lt 2$. My solution during the contest was the following: Using the triangular inequality, $|z|^p + \frac{1}{|z| ^ p} \ge |z^p + \frac{1}{z^p}| \ge |z^q + \frac{1}{z^q}|\ge |z|^q - \frac{1}{|z| ^ q}$. So $|z|^p - |z| ^ q + \frac{1}{|z| ^ p} + \frac{1}{|z| ^ q} \ge 0$. Now, here comes the mistake: I assumed that $|z| ^ p - |z| ^ q \ge 0$ which, in my mind, came form the last inequality. Of course this is wrong, but in the  heat of competition I thought it is right. I will stop here since the rest of the solution contains a really embarassing mistake and the proof is invalid once the mistake is made. So, how could I have solved it?

Answer (score 0):

> Here I give a weaker result $\color{red}{\left|z+\dfrac1z\right|\leq 2}$ than $\left|z+\dfrac{1}{z}\right|<2$.

Let $$x_{n} = z^{n} + 1/z^{n}, n=0,1,2, \cdots.$$
Suppose
that $|x_1|=\left|z+\frac1z\right|>2$.
We have that
$$x_1x_{n} = x_{n-1} + x_{n+1},$$
therefore
$$x_1= \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n}}+\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}.$$
Furthermore, let
$$ y_{n} = \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}},n=1,2,\cdots,$$
then we have
$$y_{n+1}=x_1-\frac{1}{y_{n}} .$$
We know that $ |y_{1}|=|x_1/2|>1 $.
By induction we can show that $ |y_{n}| > 1 $.
Indeed, if $
|y_{n}|>1 $, then
$$ |y_{n+1}|=\left|x_1-\frac{1}{y_{n}} \right|\geqslant |x_1|-\frac{1}{|y_{n}|}>2-1=1.$$
Therefore
$|y_{n}|>1 $ for every $ n=1,2,\cdots $ , so $|x_{n}|>|x_{n-1}|$ for
every $ n=1,2,\cdots$. But there exists $p, q \in \mathbb{N}, p < q$ such that $$|x_p| \ge |x_q|.$$